# 3 circles nested inside each other css

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to create this Logo with CSS

[Logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrL6A.png)

The Reason I want to recreate in CSS is so that I can animate each individual circle? I am using Materialize Framework here is a copy of my first horrible attempt.

```css
.hero {
  background-color: #7EEDE2;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
.circleOne {
  margin: auto;
  top: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-top-left-radius: 100px;
  border-top-right-radius: 100px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100px;
  border: 10px solid gray;
  border-bottom: 0;
}
.circleTwo {
  margin: auto;
  top: 50%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-top-left-radius: 100px;
  border-top-right-radius: 100px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100px;
  border: 10px solid gray;
  border-bottom: 0;
}
.circleThree {
  margin: auto;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-top-left-radius: 100px;
  border-top-right-radius: 100px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100px;
  border: 10px solid gray;
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!--Import Google Font-->
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!-- Import Framework -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/css/materialize.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
    <!--Import Style Sheets-->
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>SpecterMedia</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="darkBlue" role="navigation">
      <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <a id="logo-container" href="#" class="brand-logo center">Secter<span>Media</span></a>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="row hero valign-wrapper">
      <div class="col s4 offset-s4">
        <div class="circleOne"><div class="circleTwo"><div class="circleThree"></div></div></div>
        <h5 class="center"> Catchy Text </h5>
        <div class="section center">
          <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large hoverable">Get Your Free Quote Now</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s12 intro">
      </div>
    <!--Import jQuery-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <!--Import frameworkjs-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You'll want to use SVG

Comment: I agree fully with Jeremy.

Comment: I'm going to disagree, I think for this kind of thing it's about as applicable to CSS as it gets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hokay, figuring out a logical way to accomplish that took a while but I believe I've got it.

The following generates 3 quarters of a circle.

```
div {
  border: 5px solid blue;
  border-top-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

3 of these were nested inside eachother and the margin spaced them out.

Sticking the plain text S within the innermost div worked fine except for the fact that you wanted the `div` elements to be transformed (rotated) and there's no way to stop that from being inherited so the S was rotating with its parent.

The S got its own element and was given absolute positioning and the container was given alignment to center it akin to a table cell:

```
#container {
  background: grey;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
}

h3 {
    line-height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
}
```

The innermost `div` was then an appropriate size that made it and its parents grow to accompany the entirety of the container so it was centered with the S, given the margins and borders it was `60px`.

Play around with it. It's relatively dynamic but you'll have to do a little bit of math to make sure everything's aligned.

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/JackHasaKeyboard/k6gw9en3/1/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "top" you need to use "margin-top" because your divs aren't absolutely or fixed positioned

```css
.hero {
  background-color: #7EEDE2;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
.circleOne {
  margin: auto;
  top: 50%;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-top-left-radius: 100px;
  border-top-right-radius: 100px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100px;
  border: 10px solid gray;
  border-bottom: 0;
}
.circleTwo {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 8%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-top-left-radius: 100px;
  border-top-right-radius: 100px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100px;
  border: 10px solid gray;
  border-bottom: 0;
}
.circleThree {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 10%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-top-left-radius: 100px;
  border-top-right-radius: 100px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100px;
  border: 10px solid gray;
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!--Import Google Font-->
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!-- Import Framework -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/css/materialize.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
    <!--Import Style Sheets-->
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>SpecterMedia</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="darkBlue" role="navigation">
      <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <a id="logo-container" href="#" class="brand-logo center">Secter<span>Media</span></a>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="row hero valign-wrapper">
      <div class="col s4 offset-s4">
        <div class="circleOne"><div class="circleTwo"><div class="circleThree"></div></div></div>
        <h5 class="center"> Catchy Text </h5>
        <div class="section center">
          <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large hoverable">Get Your Free Quote Now</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s12 intro">
      </div>
    <!--Import jQuery-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <!--Import frameworkjs-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```